# Не устанавливается библиотека Opentele в python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку opentele, но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

Скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал очень много вариантов решения этой проблемы, но ничего не получилось

Comment: Пробовали обновить wheel?